# interpreting php as plain text when using php function require

Tags: php, require, plaintext

I have main site to which i put code using require function, but when i add php functions into it, they appear as plain text. The php code is rather long so i won't paste it here. Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks

ok i am adding some code:

require part with only one function:

```
<?php
$content=<<<EOF
echo 'hello';
EOF;
require 'whatever.php';
?>
```

and main part:

```
<?php
echo <<<CONT
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="container">
        $content
        </div>
        <div id="add_func">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
CONT;
?>
```

Comment: At least put the code that does the inclusion, and an *excerpt* of the output if not all of it?

Comment: why not to write a test code to reproduce a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get rid of heredoc

require part

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
require 'whatever.php';
?>
```

main part

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="container">
        <?php echo $content ?>
        </div>
        <div id="add_func">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

that's all
PHP is not Perl, heredoc is useless here, even if properly used.
Just never use this ugly syntax.

Comment: but i would have to use echo ''; on each line ?

Comment: @kasper do you see echo on each line here? PHP can output HTML directly http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @kasper this is very handy feature of PHP, making php both engine and template language. Main part gather the data and then include template part, which consists of HTML and basic programming instructions.

Comment: ok i'm beeing dumb or something but why call undefinied $content?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that You wrap your code in `<?php.....?>` tags.

**Update:**

No need to use the heredoc syntax for what you are doing, you could modify you code like this:

```
<?php
  echo 'hello';
  require 'whatever.php';
?>
```

And:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="container">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="add_func">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, i have done that. Even the simple require like that :

<?php
$content=<<<EOF
echo 'hello';
EOF;
require '...php';
?>

gives me: echo 'hello'; on the site
both files are wrapped in <?php ... ?>

Comment: @kesper: Make sure that there is no SPACE/INDENTATION before ending `EOF`. Also it would be easier if you could post your code in your question above.

Comment: that code should give echo \'hello\', you can't use functions/language constructs from within heredocs.